# Unable to see URL path setting menu for a user edit page

Tags: users, path-aliases

I want to see "URL path setting" tab which appears while editing any content, but can't see it while editing a user. need help or suggestion regarding this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download & install [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module & then check.